# Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Controllers log to Stackdriver

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-stackdriver, ingress

I'm using **Nginx Ingress Controller** on GKE and I want to send its logs to **Stackdriver** with the following format https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#HttpRequest. At the moment it’s just sending the plain **text payload**. Has anyone done this?

Comment: https://dev.to/bzon/send-gke-nginx-ingress-controller-logs-to-stackdriver-2ih4

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved following this guide https://dev.to/bzon/send-gke-nginx-ingress-controller-logs-to-stackdriver-2ih4

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers to prevent link rot. Instead, add the most relevant information from the link to your answer or alternatively, post the link as a comment instead of an answer. See [this](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) help center article for further information.